# How to restart Airflow webserver and scheduler?

Tags: python, webserver, etl, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Is there any way to safely restart *Airflow* webserver and/or scheduler on a server?

I am connecting to the server itself through the *SSH*.

When restarting webserver I just kill the process in the specific port.
Not sure how to do this for scheduler.

Maybe there is some option to run both webserver and scheduler in a way allowing to keep control on them (restart, stop and so on)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If tied to `systemctl` you can restart the webserver as

```
sudo systemctl restart airflow-webserver
```

Comment: thanks! In case I would do it in this way, the scheduler will be killed, right? And I need to restart the scheduler again?